# Linux, Bash execute commands in script after spawned process has ended

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Writing a small bash script.
I have a command that spawns a process then returns, leaving the spawned process running. I need to wait for the spawned process to terminate, then run some commands. How can I do this?

The specific case is:

```
VBoxManage startvm "my_vm"
#when my_vm closes
do_things
```

However, I've encountered this issue before in other contexts, so if possible I'm looking for a general solution, rather than just one relating to virtualbox vm's.

Comment: Do you have a reliable way to identify the process you want to wait for?

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer, and it's not pretty

```
tail --pid=$pid -f /dev/null
```

In the context of a VBox vm, the following heroic one-liner has proved successful.

```
VBoxManage startvm "my_vm"; tail --pid=$(awk '/Process ID:/ {print $4;}' /path_to/my_vm/Logs/VBox.log) -f /dev/null; echo hello
```

Running this, I was able to see that 'hello' was not output until after my_vm had shut down.

Good grief, there needs to be a better way of doing that than a side effect of an option of a command out of left-field. Any better answers? Please....

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not think you can generalize VirtualBox (or any process that spawns processes in the background) to one-size-fits-all solution.

Here is a VirtualBox specific answer.

As you noticed VBox runs the machine (and a bunch other things) in the background. But you can query `VBoxManage` for what is running:

```
vm_name="my_vm"
VBoxManage startvm $vm_name
while [[ `VBoxManage list runningvms | grep $vm_name` ]]; do
    echo Sleeping ...
    sleep 5
done
echo Done!
do_things
```

Hopefully you can tune this to your specific needs.